# How do I find a point on the surface of a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do I find a point on a sphere knowing its radius and center point ?

I have a sphere:  $$x^2+(y-1)^2+(z+3)^2=16$$
Obviously its center point is $(0,1,-3)$ and its radius is $4$.
I am asked to find the minimum and maximum distance to point $(1,1,1)$
So nearest point would be the touch point with the surface, and farthest point would be the touchpoint + distance of diameter.

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: Construct the line through the center and (1,1,1). Find the intersections of the line with the circle.

Comment: @GitGud I am studying this in another language, so you'd have to elaborate what multipliers are.

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik how do i find intersections of line with circle ?

Comment: @LenaBru Useful trick: google it, open english wikipage and then switch to whatever language you want.

Comment: Suggestion for the future: check out the [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Comment: The line has direction $(1,1,1)-(0,1,-3)=(1,0,4)$. So go from the center of the sphere 4 units in that direction, to get $(0,1,-3)+4/\sqrt{5}(1,0,4)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Translate** the centre of the sphere  to the origin. Then $(1,1,1)$ is translated to $(1-0,1-1,1-(-3))$, that is, to $(1,0,4)$.

The line through the origin and $(1,0,4)$ has parametric equation $x=t$, $y=0$, $z=4t$. Substitute in $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$. That will give you the two intersection points, and the rest is easy.

**Remark:** This is an instance of the technique *Transform, Solve, Transform Back*. Except if we only want the distances, we do not have to transform back.

In fact, we do not even have to do algebra, unless we want the points. For by spherical symmetry the minimum and maximum *distances* depend only on the distance of $(1,0,4)$ from the origin. So we can use instead the point $(\sqrt{17},0,0)$ and then read off the answer.

Comment: Um, this technique requires geometric thinking, and I get the feeling this problem is meant to be solved by finding the minimum and maximum values of a function subject to some constraint, since the tags are calculus and multivariable calculus.

Comment: Could be. OP has been pointed to Lagrange Multipliers. Perhaps someone will post a solution using that. The shift would still be convenient.

Comment: If no one does, I will try to be useful and give a Lagrange multipliers solution. But certainly will wait for a while, unless contacted by OP.

Comment: @AndréNicolas i looked further in my book, the Lagrange multipliers are 3 chapters forward to this question, which means this question should be solvable without it. I don't know Lagrange multipliers :(

Comment: Well, the solution I gave is more basic, and takes less calculation than Lagrange multipliers. Another approach would be to parametrize the sphere. Again, more work.

Answer (score 2):

The line has direction $(1,1,1)-(0,1,-3)=(1,0,4)$. So go from the center of the sphere 4 units in that direction, to get $(0,1,-3)+4/\sqrt{17}(1,0,4)=(4/\sqrt{17},1,-3+16/\sqrt{17})$.

Comment: To make it clearer, you could explain why that IS 4 units in that direction. That is, explain that $1/\sqrt5(1,0,4)$ is a unit vector and 4 of it goes 4 units.

Answer (score 1):

The distance from a point on the sphere to the point $p = (1,1,1)$ is

$$f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2}$$

And your $x$, $y$, and $z$ values are subject to the constrain function
$$g(x,y,z)=x^2+(y-1)^2+(z+3)^2$$
where
$$g(x,y,z) = 16$$

With the above info, solving
$$\nabla{f} = \lambda \cdot \nabla g$$

for $x$, $y$, and $z$ should give you your solutions. $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$, and $\lambda$ is just a dummy variable to help solve the problem.

Comment: A comment: it's just as valid and a great deal easier to express the Lagrangian multiplier condition using $f^2(x,y)$ instead of $f$.